# How to create dynamic models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

First, I'm very new to Rails, I have a rather basic questions concerning models.

I have an Event model with a has_many attributes called Properties. I generated my Property model but the attributes have to be defined, however, properties can change according to the event.

Example:

- Event A will have 4 properties, one will be a boolean and the rest will be strings.
- Event B will only have 1 integer property

How can I create a Property model with "dynamic" attributes?

Thanks for the help.

Ps: I'm using SQLite

Comment: Just curious. Why do you need dynamic attributes? Why cant you store properites in event table. Create column for each property. Some columns will not have data.

Comment: Adding X columns as I start adding properties does not seem like a good practice. I'd rather have one property column only with a JSON. But I'm still not comfortable with working with Postgres and rails. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, postgreql has JSON built in, but if you're using any other database, you can set your model up with [serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) like so

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  serialize :property, JSON
end
```

and then get the parsing/saving done automagically for you, no need to clutter your code doing it on your own

```
Event.create(name: 'Famous Person Concert Thing', property: { artist: 'Someone famous, most likely', kids_allowed: false })                            
#  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "events" ("name", "property", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Famous Person Concert Thing"], ["property", "{\"artist\":\"Someone famous, most likely\",\"kids_allowed\":false}"], ["created_at", "2017-07-15 18:47:05.949921"], ["updated_at", "2017-07-15 18:47:05.949921"]]

Event.last.property
# => {"artist"=>"Someone famous, most likely", "kids_allowed"=>false}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data as a serialized hash in a string column in sqlite. This way you are more flexible with the kind of data you store. 
For more native support of json columns you should think about using [postgresql](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#json-and-jsonb).

[Parsing and saving hashes with sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065966/how-to-store-json-data-in-sqlite)