# Insert Json into sqlite data base

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to create a table and insert below json response into sqlite data base.

```
{ 
 “parameters”: 
   [ { “name”: “Test”, “value”: “Testing”, “message”: “Success” } ], 
 “statusCode”: 200 
}
```

How can I create Database table as below and insert json response.

`Parameters name,Value ,Message,statuscode`

JSON validation is done in Java script.
How can I achieve this in Ruby on rails?

Comment: You can store them by converting them to string for by using the latest json1 plugin (https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store json data in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065966/how-to-store-json-data-in-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks.json validation done in java script file.When I click Get Val button  it will call http_response method in Js file and display json response in text field.I need to store that response in data base.

Comment: How to implement above in Ruby on Rails?